# Select all tables and exclude the div

Tags: selenium, xpath

I'm trying to do some stuff with python and selenium but I can't get my xpath to work. I have the following code :

```
<div id="ctl00_Main_treeCategories">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a id="ctl00_Main_treeCategoriesn0">Online Catalogus</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="ctl00_Main_treeCategoriesn0Nodes" style="display:block;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a id="ctl00_Main_treeCategoriesn1">Dakraam</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="ctl00_Main_treeCategoriesn1Nodes" style="display:block;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td>
                    <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="treeNode ctl00_Main_treeCategories_2"><a class="ctl00_Main_treeCategories_0 treeNode ctl00_Main_treeCategories_1">Dakraam Duette® &amp; Plissé Saaaaahade</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
        <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="treeNode ctl00_Main_treeCategories_2" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    <a class="ctl00_Main_treeCategories_0 treeNode ctl00_Main_treeCategories_1">Duette® Fixé &amp; Plissé Shadeeeee</a>
                 </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I try to select all tables within the ctl00_Main_treeCategoriesn0Nodes div, and exclude the div on the first level within (ctl00_Main_treeCategoriesn1Nodes).

I tried :

```
//*[contains(@id, "ctl00_Main_treeCategoriest")]/div/table/
```

but this gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two errors on the XPath:

- Mispelling of the id (that `t` at the end)
- Trailing / (not necessary)

  ```
  //*[contains(@id, "ctl00_Main_treeCategories")]/div[not(@id="ctl00_Main_treeCategoriesn1Nodes")]/table
  ```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/SusIZ

**Edit:** Excluded inside `ctl00_Main_treeCategoriesn1Nodes` divs

Comment: wow, stupid mistake, sorry about that! But I then still get the contents of the div within. I only want the tables and skip the div

Comment: I fixed it, I think it's working how you want it now.